# Extract bigquery table huge data into multiple files into local and not to google storage

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

We are having service account credentials of a google project. Using that, we need to extract data from a table and load into a table in different project.

Approach 1:
Extract the data into google storage --> Download the files to local --> load into a table in different project.
When, we use client.extract_table method, we will be able to export the data to files in google storage. But, we do not have storage.buckets.create permission. Due to that, bucket cannot be created to export the files into google storage.
Is it possible to extract the data into files in local?

Approach2:
Read the table table data and write as dataframe using pandas. But, it requires readsession.create permission. It is not available for the service account credentials.

Is there any possibility to extract the files into local without adding any new permission?

Comment: Why do you not reuse an existing bucket instead of creating a new one?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Issue may occur if a bucket does not exist

Comment: Sure, but you haven't other solutions! You can only extract from bigQuery to Cloud Storage, and then download the files.